# Connect C++ native app to Firefox WebExtensions add-on with native messaging

Tags: c++, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions, chrome-native-messaging

I want to make a easy example Firefox add-on using Native messaging. Here is my code:

**Native App:**

```cpp
void SendDataToExtension(string message)
{
    _setmode(_fileno(stdout), O_BINARY);
    try {
        unsigned int len = message.length();
        std::string message = "{\"text\": \"This is a response message\"}";
        unsigned int lenStr = str.length();
        std::cout << char(((lenStr >> 0) & 0xFF))
            << char(((lenStr >> 8) & 0xFF))
            << char(((lenStr >> 16) & 0xFF))
            << char(((lenStr >> 24) & 0xFF));
        std::cout << str.c_str();
        std::cout.flush();
    }
    catch (...) {
        throw;
    }
}

string OpenStandardStreamIn()
{
    std::cout.setf(std::ios_base::unitbuf);
    _setmode(_fileno(stdin), _O_BINARY);
    unsigned int c, t = 0;
    size_t pos = 0, m = 0;
    std::string inp;
    inp = "";
    t = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
        t += (unsigned int)pow(256.0f, i) * getchar();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < (int)t; i++) {
        c = getchar();
        inp += c;
    }
    return inp;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    string input = "";
    while ((input = OpenStandardStreamIn()) != "")
    {
        try 
        {
            if (input.compare("ping")) {
                SendDataToExtension("pong");
            }
        }
        catch (...) { throw; }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**JS code:**

```js
var port = browser.runtime.connectNative("ping_pong");

port.onMessage.addListener((response) => {
  console.log("Received: " + response);
});

browser.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(() => {
  console.log("Sending:  ping");
  port.postMessage("ping");
});
```

When I added the add-on to Firefox, I got 2 errors:

```
stderr output from native app ping_pong:   File "ping_pong.exe", line 1

stderr output from native app ping_pong: SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\x90' in file ping_pong.exe on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

(Don't have native-messaging tag. So, I used chrome-native-messaging tag, but I want to make this sample run on Firefox)

**EDIT1:**

This 2 errors is my mistake. I just remove 'python' on ping_pong_win.bat to solved them.

But I got another problem. When I run this test, this is result:

```
Sending:  ping
Received: [object Object]
```

Seem like native app doesn't work.

**EDIT2:**
I debugged, Native app got "ping" message but It can't send the response "pong" message

**Solved:**
Native app sent response to browser, I just print wrong: @@

```
port.onMessage.addListener((response) => {
  console.log("Received: " + response.text);
});
```

Comment: I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. However, an actual answer/solution should **not** be edited into your Question. In general, you should [edit] the Question to *clarify the Question*, but not to include an Answer within the Question. You should create your own Answer with the code you used to solve your problem, then accept it (the system may require a 48 hour delay prior to accepting your own answer). When you have solved the problem yourself, [answering your own question is encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).